# Internationalization with Angular and Bootstrap 3

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, internationalization, arabic, arabic-support

I'm currently working on an website project for which the front-end logic is based on angular and on bootstrap 3 for the design.

The website should be available in both french and arabic languages with french as the default language, and so not only the text content have to be translated but also the direction (right-to-left for arabic) of the web pages must be handled properly.

I looked around for a while but I couldn't find any angular module that can do both.

there is however some modules and libraries that help do either of the two features needed.

for i18n : [angular-l10n](https://github.com/robisim74/angular-l10n), and here ngx-translate

and for rtl : [bootstrap-rtl](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl) and here bootstrap-3-arabic among few others.

there is no problem with the first one, but for the later it seems to be difficult since it is a css style library it may need us to build the project twice, one with the default bs3 library for ltr direction and the other with bootstrap-rtl library included for the rtl content.

now my questions are :

1 - is there any module/component that is both angular and bootstrap3 compatible and that can handle both features

2 - if no, is there a way to handle this dynamically without the the need to build the project twice